# Benefits/Examples of using a Service Layer in MVC patterns

Tags: php, zend-framework, service, layer

We're contemplating implementing a [service layer (as described by Martin Fowler)](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) within our current development as a way to process common processes within our system.

What are peoples thoughts on a service layer? What examples of process' have people implemented service layers for? What are the benfits/drawbacks etc?

We currently use the Zend Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, a service layer is just an API that tries to separate code that has nothing to do with data persistence from the rest of your model. Hierarchical controllers can help here.